# Unable to interact with text boxes and button inside View in a ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I am unable to interact with the text boxes and button in my view which is inside a scrollview. I have tried changing the height  of view with no luck.

[image]

Comment: Did you set the delegate of your text boxes? Have you set `User Interaction Enabled` at the container view level? Or other levels for that matter?

Comment: @TravisGriggs yes user interaction are all checked

Answer (score 0):

This is because your UIControls are inside a UIView, which causes the scrollView to cancel touches before they receive them.
What you should do is:

1- Create a subclass of UIScrollView and add:
Create a subclass of UIScrollview with

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view {
  return NO;
}
```

2- In your viewController, add:

```
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```